# Вопрос, что мне делать ошибкой identifier expected? Java

Tags: java, java-11

Пишу код, у меня выскакивает ошибка:
`identifier expected`

Я думал в чём заключается сама ошибка, но не хватает знаний и опыта.

Ошибка на 15 строке, int.
`identifier expected`

Сам скрипт:

```
     * Расчёт стоимости проезда исходя из массы и высоты
     */
    private static int calculatePrice(Car car)
    {
        int price = 0;
        int carHeight = car.height;
        if (carHeight > controllerMaxHeight)
        {
            blockWay("высота вашего ТС превышает высоту пропускного пункта!");
            return -1;
        } else if (carHeight > passengerCarMaxHeight) {
            double weight = car.weight;
            //Грузовой автомобиль
            if (weight > passengerCarMaxWeight)
            { int
                 return price = passengerCarPrice;
                if (car.hasVehicle) {
                    price = price + vehicleAdditionalPrice;

                }
            }
            //Легковой автомобиль
            else {
                return  price = cargoCarPrice;
            }
        } else {
          return price = passengerCarPrice;
        }
        return price;
    }
```

Comment: 1) В Java нельзя просто написать `int`, да еще и без `;` в конце. Если вы написали `int`, то вы, наверное, хотели объявить какую-то переменную `int a = 42;`?

Comment: 2) `return` это выход из функции, после `return ...;` не может следовать никакого кода (в текущем блоке кода), Java не даст скомпилировать такой код.

Comment: 3) запись `return a = b;` избыточна и эквивалентна `return b;`

Comment: Попробуйте переписать ваш код так, чтобы в этой функции был только один метод `return` в самом конце: `return price`.

Answer (score 1):

Давайте посмотрим на этот кусочек кода

```
{ int
    return price = passengerCarPrice;
    if (car.hasVehicle) {
```

здесь явно видно, что int не нужен, либо хотели что то дописать.

конструкция return price = passengerCarPrice; также вызывает кучу вопросов. Вы хотите возвратить результат присваивания? Хотя посмотрев на общий код, возникает ощущение, что Вы хотите присвоить в price и выйти, так как в самом конце есть return price;

Если так, Вы можете упросить. Вместо

```
return  price = cargoCarPrice;
```

пишите просто

```
return  cargoCarPrice;
```

с метода сразу выйдет и значение price уже не будет иметь значение.